# How to prove using Lagrange's theorem $a^{p-1}\equiv1\bmod p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove using Lagrange's theorem $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$.

Here, exponentiation (repeated multiplication) is of concern.

So, first want to show this property in action.
Below shown for two values of $p=5,7$ with
operation of exponentiation, the desired property, i.e. for $4$-th power $\equiv 1\bmod 5$, and $6$-th power $\equiv 1\bmod 7$, for all elements of the group. I.e., the last column follows the rule.

Say, $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &a^1&a^2&a^3&a^4\\
\hline
1 & 1& 1& 1&1\\
\hline
2 & 2 & 4& 3& 1\\
\hline
3 & 3 & 4& 2& 1\\
\hline
4 & 4 & 1& 4& 1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

The same pattern occurs for $p=7$, as shown in the below table :
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &a^1&a^2&a^3&a^4&a^5&a^6\\
\hline
1 & 1& 1& 1&1&1&1\\
\hline
2 & 2 & 4& 1& 2&4&1\\
\hline
3 & 3 & 2& 6& 4&5&1\\
\hline
4 & 4 & 2& 1& 4&2&1\\
\hline
5 & 5 & 4& 6 & 2 &3&1\\
\hline
6 & 6 & 1& 6 & 1 &6&1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Doubt 1: But, none of the above is a group, so can the Lagrange theorem apply?

It says: order of element divides order of group.$- \tag{1}$

There is no group (wrt, exponential operation), and no order hence comes into view.

So, cannot say that can use property (1) to derive the given property from that.

*Edit :* expect a simple answer, so given tag accordingly.

*Edit 1:* as per suggestion by @Cpc - to see instead the group properties in multiplication table, which seems is due to the reason that basically exponentiation is repeated multiplication.

So, rather than checking if $<\mathbb {Z^*}, \wedge >$ is a group, need check that $<\mathbb{Z^*}, \times > $ is a group table or not.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \times \bmod 5 &1&2&3&4\\
\hline
1 & 1& 2& 3&4\\
\hline
2 & 2 & 4& 1& 3\\
\hline
3 & 3 & 1& 4& 2\\
\hline
4 & 4 & 3& 2& 1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\times \bmod 7 &1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
1 & 1& 2& 3&4&5&6\\
\hline
2 & 2 & 4& 6& 1&3&5\\
\hline
3 & 3 & 6& 2& 5&1&4\\
\hline
4 & 4 & 1& 5& 2&6&3\\
\hline
5 & 5 & 3& 1 & 6 &4&2\\
\hline
6 & 6 & 4& 4 & 3 &2&1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

*Edit 2:* Also, is there any other such problem in multiplication (similar to exponentiation operation here) where instead need check addition table (similar to addition operation here) for group properties?

Comment: Hint: Consider the the cyclic group generated by $a$ (multiplicatively), which is a subgroup of $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^*$.

Comment: Because of Lagramge´s theorem the orders of the elements of the multiplicative groups $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ must divide the order of these groups which are $p-1$ for $p$ prime

Comment: @PeterMelech In first table, why last row doesn't have entire group? It has only two elements. Similarly, in second row; only two elements. Single element in last column; the mainstay for the problem; also is issue. In second table, even more issues.

Comment: Please first search for answers before posting questions to avoid duplication.

Comment: @jitenLet $G$ be a finite group of order $|G|$ . Then for any $a\in G$ , $a^{|G|}=e $. 
 (Direct consequence of Lagrange's theorem) 


 Let $U(\Bbb{Z}_n) $ denotes the group of units of the ring $(\Bbb{Z_n}, +, •) $

$$U(\Bbb{Z}_n) =\{a\in \Bbb{Z_n} : a\le n \text{ and } (a, n) =1\}$$( see [here][1] ) 

$|U(\Bbb{Z}_p)|=\varphi(p)=p-1$

Now use the first result. 


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2849576/977780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See you actually start with a *ring*, $\Bbb Z_p$.  Or, actually,  it's even a *field*.  And for any field,  the nonzero elements form a (multiplicative) group, also denoted $\Bbb F^*$.

The group is then$\Bbb Z_p^×\cong\Bbb Z_{p-1}$, the group of units (of the ring).

So in your examples we get $\Bbb Z_5^×\cong\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_7^×\cong\Bbb Z_6$.

When $p$ is prime the group of units  has order $p-1$.

And by Lagrange anything raised to the power $n=|G|$ is equal to $e$.

Comment: Seems stuck as why it is a group. If you can show the group property in any of the table(s) given, then would be highly thankful.

Comment: It's a group because every element has an inverse.  The other requirements for a group are already in place.

Comment: In first table, why last row doesn't have entire group? It has only two elements. Similarly, in second row; only two elements. Single element in last column; the mainstay for the problem; also is issue. In second table, even more issues.

Comment: If you change to a table of multiplication for the nonzero elements  of the field,  you will see that you have a group.

Comment: Thanks, kindly see the edited OP.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 2):

You're working in [the group of invertible elements modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n), denoted e.g. $(\mathbb{Z}_n^*,\times)$.

- The set is $\{i \in \mathbb{Z}_n : \gcd(i,n)=1\}$, and
- The binary operation is multiplication modulo $n$.

So yes, Lagrange's Theorem applies here.  When $n$ is a prime, the order of the group is $n-1$ (noting that $\gcd(0,n) \neq 1$).

When $n$ is prime, you're rediscovering [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), otherwise we have [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Comment: Your first link states about multiplicative inverse, by use of Bezout lemma, for $a$ in $ax\equiv 1$. Want to add that though exponentiation is repeated multiplication, but still $a^x \neq ax$.

Comment: Might be not able to understand why it is a group, and that is the core issue then.

Comment: I've always just thought of it as the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).  The main thing is to avoid conflating $\mathbb{Z}_n$ under addition with $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ under multiplication.  They do not have the same number of elements, nor the same binary operation.

Comment: Also, is there any other such problem in multiplication (similar to exponentiation operation here) where instead need check addition table (similar to addition operation here) for group properties?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).